# Embedded youtube videos blocked by network admins stopping web page loading

Tags: html, youtube, embed, permission-denied

We've developed a website for one of our clients which has some embedded youtube videos. Unfortunately, the clients internet filtering software blocks youtube access - this cannot and will not be changed because it's their (archaic) policy.

The problem is that our client cannot load the website because it gets hung up on trying to load the embedded videos. Apparently a regular html page with a 'forbidden' message appears when someone tries to access youtube - so I would have thought the browser would give up and move on.. but no.

Does anyone have any simple suggestions as to how this can be resolved? Perhaps the 'denied' message needs to have a 403 header to get the browser to give up...alternatively is there a nice way to do this in the html?

Comment: Could you make a request for YouTube's `favicon.ico` in JavaScript, and on the `error` event remove the YouTube videos?

Comment: Could do, was hoping for something more simple, like a clever <param> setting or something..

Comment: I'm not aware of any `param` to do it, unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, that issue hasn't shown up with my website. If YouTube is blocked, the video just doesn't show up; page loading isn't completely stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use IFrames?

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p> anything outside of the frame</p>
  <iframe src="page_with_video.htm>
   <p> Sorry you can't acess this</p>
  </iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

and then you could just embed the videos on an external page, which should cause the page with the videos to load separately from the rest.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.. we're currently trying harder to get the IT dept of our client to fix their internet filter, but this sounds like a fairly good solution if that fails.

Comment: We gave up in the end, they wouldn't budge so we just explained to our client to fix their IT team.